# Matching a string with regular expression returns null

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to match a string for two cases by a single regular expressing in JavaScript. The string can be in any one of the given formats

```
//Singapore
//Singapore (country)
```

I have tried the following regular expression to match the strings

```
"singapore".match(/(.*) (?:\((.*)\))?/)
//null
"singapore (country)".match(/(.*) (?:\((.*)\))?/)
//["singapore (country)", "singapore", "country"]
```

I want both the results to return an array like the 2nd case where the 3rd entry in the array can be undefined/empty or not present at all but the result should not be null.

Can this be done by a single regular expression. If yes then what is the mistake in the above expression

Comment: @JamesThorpe yes it can contain a space

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the space in the optional group, because it's not here in the case of just `"singapore"`: `/^([^\(]*)(?: \(([^\)]*)\))?$/`